# How to iterate through an ArrayList of integer?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList of Integer` of `{1, 3, 4, 5 , 6}`

how do I iterate through the `ArrayList` so that i can print out the values in this manner in each loop?

```
1 and 3  
1 and 4  
1 and 5  
1 and 6  
3 and 4  
3 and 5  
3 and 6  
4 and 5  
4 and 6  
5 and 6
```

I have tried doing a `foreach` loop, followed by a `for` loop and remove one object after the next but I encounter the **ConcurrentModificationException**. any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Nested loop + omit if pair is the same value

Comment: Why do you need to remove elements from the list?  Is that part of the actual requirement?  Show your code.

Comment: wow. those downvotes. i'm actually trying to solve a problem and this question solves part of it. i will post the problem after i solved it. i will probably post the entire problem here if you guys are interested in solving it. it will be fun to see what solutions you guys come up with too. upvote this if you're interested.

Comment: i mean add a comment below if you're interested

Comment: I suppose there are downvotes because you did not post any code and it looks like a simple for loop at first sight. But the `ConcurrentModificationException` is what you should have put in your title. Is there multi-threading involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want
- Iterate and remove first element

To avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating and removing element use standard old-fashioned for loops instead of foreach.

```
do
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.println(list.get(0) + " and " + list.get(j));
            }
            list.remove(0);
        }
        while (list.size() != 0);
```

Comment: how can i forget the old fashion do while loop! this is what i need for now. thanks mate!

Comment: you should accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: is it possible for me to add an if condition that "breaks the loop" within the for loop?

Comment: Yup, you can definitely break the loop on basis of your condition.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + " and " + list.get(j));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is `remove` and `ConcurrentModificationException`